# Correct way to use insertBefore()

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a element using insertBefore but it's not working.

what is the difference between those 2 codes? why does one work and the other does not.

working code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G7KF9MQKIA2C

not working: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G7KF978GWI24

when insertBefore is used without parent divs it seems to be able to find the ID of the div I want. I'm currently trying to use this into a more complex file and it's not working as well it shows "Node was not found".

Comment: The 'currentDiv' is not a child from the 'document.body'. You need to use 'document.body.firstElementChild'. You need to get the parent of the child and use the `insertBefore` on it.

Comment: The insertBefore() method inserts a node as a child, right before an existing child, which you specify.

Answer (score 0):

The parent child connection is what is important for that function to work

> The insertBefore() method inserts a node as a child, right before an
>   existing child, which you specify.

You code which didn't work would work like this (see definition again).
The one which works is because the parent html element is the body html element.

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="A"> 

  a
  </div>
  <div id="B"> 
  b

  </div>
  <div id="C"> 
  c

  </div>
</div>
<script>

var newDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
newDiv.innerHTML = "asdf";
newDiv.id = "idtest";

var currentDiv = document.getElementById("B"); 
document.getElementById('parent').insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
</script>
```